# How to get the file name which just got modified using windows batch program

Tags: batch-file, directory, last-modified

I am trying to solve a problem where I am monitoring a specific  directory. My batch program monitors for the files that gets modified and records them in a txt file. So far I have written the code where it can detect when a file changes and can print a time stamp.

But now I also need it to record the name of the file that just got modified. Can anyone please help me with this. Here is what I have done so far:

```
@Echo Off
Set _Delay=10
Set _Monitor=C:\Users\MMurshed\Desktop\New folder (3)
Set _Base=%temp%\BaselineState.dir
Set _Chck=%temp%\ChkState.dir
Set _OS=6
Ver|Findstr /I /C:"Version 5">Nul
If %Errorlevel%==0 Set _OS=5 & Set /A _Delay=_Delay*1000
:_StartMon
Call :_SetBaseline "%_Base%" "%_Monitor%"
:_MonLoop
If %_OS%==5 (Ping 1.0.0.0 -n 1 -w %_Delay%>Nul) Else Timeout %_Delay%>Nul
Call :_SetBaseline "%_Chck%" "%_Monitor%"
FC /A /L "%_Base%" "%_Chck%">Nul
If %ErrorLevel%==0 Goto _MonLoop
::
:: Insert code to run when a change occurs
::
Echo.Change Detected
Echo.Timestamp = %date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,8%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%


Goto :_StartMon
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Subroutine
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:_SetBaseline
If Exist "%temp%\tempfmstate.dir" Del "%temp%\tempfmstate.dir"
For /F "Tokens=* Delims=" %%I In ('Dir /S "%~2"') Do (
Set _Last=%%I
>>"%temp%\tempfmstate.dir" Echo.%%I
)
>"%~1" Findstr /V /C:"%_Last%" "%temp%\tempfmstate.dir"
Goto :EOF
```

Comment: It may not be the technology you were seeking, but perhaps it could help. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access WMI from a VBScript code embedded in the batch file to monitor directory changes and do what you need inside this code (currently it prints the info to console):

```
@echo off
set "vbsfile=%temp%\dirwatch%random%.vbs"
>"%vbsfile%" (
    for /f "delims=: tokens=* eol=" %%a in ('findstr /b ":::" "%~dpnx0"') do echo.%%a
)
cscript //nologo "%vbsfile%"
del "%vbsfile%"
exit /b

:::intInterval = "10"
:::strDrive = "c:"
:::strFolder = replace("\Users\MMurshed\Desktop\New folder (3)", "\", "\\")
:::strComputer = "."
:::
:::Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_
::: strComputer & "\root\cimv2" )
:::
:::Set events = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery( _
::: "Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent" _
::: & " Within " & intInterval _
::: & " Where Targetinstance Isa 'CIM_DataFile'" _
::: & " And TargetInstance.Drive='" & strDrive & "'"_
::: & " And TargetInstance.Path='" & strFolder & "'")
:::
:::Do
::: Set fileEvent = events.NextEvent()
::: Set fileInfo = fileEvent.TargetInstance
:::
::: Select Case fileEvent.Path_.Class
:::     Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"
:::         WScript.Echo "Created: " & fileInfo.Name
:::     Case "__InstanceDeletionEvent"
:::         WScript.Echo "Deleted: " & fileInfo.Name
:::     Case "__InstanceModificationEvent"
:::         Set prevFile = fileEvent.PreviousInstance
:::         For Each prop In fileInfo.Properties_
:::             If prop.Value <> prevFile.Properties_(prop.Name) Then
:::                 WScript.Echo "Changed:        " & fileInfo.Name
:::                 WScript.Echo "Property:       " & prop.Name
:::                 WScript.Echo "Previous value: " & prevFile.Properties_(prop.Name)
:::                 WScript.Echo "New value:      " & prop.Value
:::                 WScript.Echo
:::             End If
:::         Next
::: End Select
:::Loop
```

P.S. Due to quota restrictions of WMI service the subfolders aren't monitored

The code is taken from [WMI and File System Monitoring](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42212/WMI-and-File-System-Monitoring.aspx) article by Uros Calakovic.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Archive Attribut to check for new or changed files (that's what it's supposed to be used to)

Windows sets this Attribute every time, a file is created or changed, so just ask Windows for "changed files" `:)`

```
@echo off
rem create some files
echo hello>a.txt
echo hello>b.txt
echo hello>c.txt
call :check
echo marking them by settting the "Archive" attribute:
attrib -a *.txt
call :check
echo changing a file
echo world>>b.txt
call :check
attrib -a *.txt
goto :eof

:check
echo ========================
echo new or changed files:
dir /b /aa-d *.txt
echo ------------------------
echo unchanged files:
dir /b /a-a-d *.txt
echo ========================
goto :eof
```

Comment: yes but it doesnt solve my issue. I need a program which will monitor a directory and look for the files which gets modified. Once it does it will record its timestamp and the filename. The directory may contain many files. So it will monitor all and record their times and names whenever they are "modified" . Can you do anything in my code so that I can extract the filename to which the time stamp refers to?

Comment: replace `dir /b /aa-d *.txt` with `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /aa-d *.txt') do echo %%~ti   %%i >>"%temp%\tempfmstate.dir"`. `%%~ti` is the timestamp of the file

Comment: ok thanks. And if I want to echo a file name what is the command?

Comment: ? `%%i` is the filename. You already use it in your original code... See `for /?` for more possibilities

Comment: i tried your thing but it doesnt work. can you modify my code because i can already get the timestamp. I just need to know which file.